# When training a neural net what could cause the net to diverge from the target as opposed to converge?

Tags: neural-network

I'm using a stochastic (incremental as opposed to batch) approach to training my neural net, and after every 1000000 iterations I print the sum of the errors of the neurons in the net. For a little while I can see this overall error decreasing steadily, and as progress begins to slow, it then seems to reverse the complete other way and the overall error begins increasing steadily. This cannot be normal behavior, and I'm not sure what could be causing it. My learning rate is set very low 0.0001.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that the train set is diverging to a wrong set..

Comment: You are printing the error of what? training set or test set?

Comment: Can you show the code that are training the net, and the code that set the new weight?